# mongodb aggregate query 64 MB limit

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I do have a table with more than a billion object like below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5893ae4f7a5449caebba5848"),
    "id" : NumberLong(1234567890),
    "inserted_at" : ISODate("2017-02-02T22:10:23.812Z")
}
```

It is saved on mongodb 3.2.11.

I insert almost 50 million new records each week and need to compare the new week's records with the previous week's.

Therefore, I have built a query like this:

```
db.getCollection('table').aggregate(
   [
        {"$group" : {
            "_id": {
                "year": { "$year": "$inserted_at"},
                "week": { "$week": "$inserted_at"}},
            "Content_IDs": { "$push": "$id"}}},
        { "$sort": {'_id.year': -1, '_id.week': -1}},
        { "$limit": 2},



        { "$group": {
             "_id": null,
             "Last": { $first: "$Content_IDs" },
             "Previous": { $last: "$Content_IDs"}
        }},

        { $project: {
            "Outgoing": { $setDifference: [ "$Previous", "$Last" ] },
            "Incoming": { $setDifference: [ "$Last", "$Previous" ] }}},
   ],
   {allowDiskUse:true}
)
```

However mongodb cannot calculate the result because of the size of the data.

The error is as below:

> assert: command failed: {     "ok" : 0,   "errmsg" : "BufBuilder attempted
>   to grow() to 134217728 bytes, past the 64MB limit.",  "code" : 13548 }

I have tried to fetch all records into Python env so that I can calculate the result there but I got the same error when I run the following pipeline on pymongo.aggregate:

```
[
            {"$group" : {
                "_id": {
                    "year": { "$year": "$inserted_at"},
                    "week": { "$week": "$inserted_at"}},
                "Content_IDs": { "$push": "$id"}}},
            { "$sort": SON([('_id.year', -1), ('_id.week', -1)])},
            { "$limit": 2}
        ]
```

It works on a smaller scale of data. How can I make this query more scalable? Any suggestions?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar problem and I started to use Spark (and Scala) to manipulate my data. There are not much memory restrictions, you can use in a cluster and it's faster than nodejs.

Comment: I think I need some clarification on this. I do not have any expertise on neither Spark nor Scala. 
Do you suggest use -Spark, i.e.- together with MongoDB via MongoDB Connector for Spark? In this case, could MongoDB provide that big amount of data to Spark to process while it cannot provide to Python? 
Thanks

Comment: Hey, Spark has connector for both Scala and Python and apparently both works fine. I just feel like mongodb standalone cannot handle the work. Spark will distribute the data and do some tricks to perform your analysis. But please be aware that I'm new on it so I might be saying tons of bullshit